# Android - InputStream's buffer size changes? This should be impossible

Tags: android, inputstream, monkey

I have this, where `mmInputStream` is an InputStream of a Bluetooth connection:

```
    int bytes;
    boolean hasData;

    while (!isInterrupted()){

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        hasData = false;

        try {
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            if (bytes > 0) {
                hasData = true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            break;
        }

        if (hasData)  {
            final String data = new String(buffer).substring(0, bytes);
        }
```

In my monkey testing (with App/UI Exerciser) I got one of these:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1022; regionStart=0; regionLength=1024
    at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
    at com.mikehelland.omgbananasremote.BluetoothConnection.run(BluetoothConnection.java:80)
```

I don't see how that would even be remotely possible for the length of the buffer to end up less than what it was initialized as, every loop of the way.

Unless I totally don't understand Java, when I pass the `buffer` array to `read()`, it is by reference, and you can't change the size of an array, so `read` shouldn't be able to change the size of `buffer` in the code above. Right?

Anyone ever seen anything like this?

Comment: I fixed the crash by checking the length of the string. I'm just really curious how the buffer size could have changed.

Answer (score 0):

So even though the buffer was 1024 the resulting string was 1022, for maybe unicode reasons?

Anyways, as a comment suggested, `String(buffer, 0, bytes)` did the trick and no need for the `substring()`.